# Web Service asmx not working on mono 4.2.3.4 Debian 8.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, web-services, mono

We host a web service .asmx (we cannot change this) on Linux/Mono

On Debian 7 - mono 3.12 it works

but on Debian 8 mono 4.2.3.4 Apache 2.4.10 we receive the following error just browsing the asmx

[image]

Strangely System.Runtime looks somehow linked to .NET CORE (but we do not use this framework)

Answer (score 2):

After adding the required assemblies from .NET, finally it turnout to be a well know bug, already reported on SO.:

[Web Services does not work in mono 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861762/web-services-does-not-work-in-mono-4#)

This has been fixed, but quite likely it will be officially available on 4.4

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37137

Answer (score 0):

System.Runtime is already existing in .NET 4.6.x.

You may be hitting a regression in Mono that the new xbuild versions have and that the old (from Mono 3.12) didn't. I think this regression has been fixed in mono master branch in [this commit](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/d44824b7f8483b2aebb6becdfac54b1206cd617e).

To check if I'm correct, you would need to compile mono yourself, or grab packages from the weekly/daily repository.